# Problem with printing values

Tags: java

As Similar to previous issue I am unable to print value on the screen. I have tested the prime mark loop and It does produce correct figures but print statements are not printing value so I can not verify the code. The code is attached below. Few Reputed people guided me to use BigInteger but I have few issue in it so I will look into that as well.

Thanks in advance for all your help and assistance.

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;

public class DH {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        int q;
        int z = 10000;
        Random generator = new Random(0);
        q = generator.nextInt(50000);

        double sk1 = generator.nextDouble();
        double sk2 = generator.nextDouble();

        for (int p = generator.nextInt(z); p < 50000; p++) {
            int j;
            for (j = 2; j < p; j++) {
                int n = p % j;
                if (n == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (p == j) {
                double a = Math.pow(q, sk1);
                double pk1 = a % p;

                double b = Math.pow(q, sk2);
                double pk2 = b % p;

                if (pk1 == pk2) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    System.out.println(p);
                    System.out.println(q);
                    System.out.println(sk1);
                    System.out.println(sk2);
                    System.out.println(pk1);
                    System.out.println(pk2);
                    System.out.print("  " + i);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know pk1==pk2 at that point during execution?  If tney're not equal you'll get no output, which sounds like what's happening.

Comment: Thanks,Jim but there is little issue print is happening 4 times and then it finish building

Comment: How about posting ur print outcome?

Comment: It is printing iterative outcome but anyway the output is below. I have to sort the repetive result and include in message digest for security class

Comment: 1091
41360
6893.095266771541
629.8563595102662
0.8314409887870612
0.6063452159973596
347.095266771541
629.8563595102662
629.8563595102662
347.095266771541
1091
41360
6893.095266771541
629.8563595102662
0.8314409887870612
0.6063452159973596
347.095266771541
629.8563595102662
629.8563595102662
347.095266771541

Answer (score 0):

Since sk1 and sk2 have different values (because they are random), pk1 and pk2 have different values too. Only case when you can have output happening is when they are equal (and that is nearly impossible). By the way, what was that "i" variable in the last output statement?

Comment: Its suppose to be p I was testing the prime no. are working or not so was checking against the series in different class, forget to change the variable